# A Monk threw three coloured darts, then spends one minute searching the battlefield, how many darts does the Monk recover?

Tags: dnd-5e, ammunition

A Monk PC has three ordinary darts. 
He's very creative and painted the darts different colours, the primary colours. One dart is red, one dart is yellow, one dart is blue.

The monk throws the three coloured darts at an opponent. 
He then spends one minute searching the battlefield, what is the monk able to recover?

Each coloured dart has a different but equal sentimental value to the monk PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A crossbowman fires three coloured bolts, then spends one minute searching the battlefield, which bolt(s) does he recover?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/165161/a-crossbowman-fires-three-coloured-bolts-then-spends-one-minute-searching-the-b)

Comment: The answer by @nitsua60 is good, I did not know at the time of posting that darts are handled differently than bolts. And so these questions are sufficiently different to warrant them being separate, having distinctly different answers.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### 0-3 darts.

Darts aren't ammunition, they're a simple ranged (thrown) weapon. (PHB p.149) So you handle them the same as you'd handle a thrown dagger, or javelin, or handaxe, or light hammer. Which is up to you and your GM: there are no rules covering this.

When I've been in this sort of situation I've allowed players to find all of the thrown weapons that make sense to find. The one that hit the dead guy? Found. The one that missed and went into the bushes? Found. The one that missed and went into the chasm? Sorry. The one that hit and stuck into the beast that ran away? Gonna need replacing.

---

<sup>I suppose the monk could find more, if you like. Could make an interesting historical aside, learning that The Great Dart Volley of DR 612 happened *here!*</sup>